# usage of pre processor definition with function prototype

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, user-defined-functions

I have to deal with two header files declaring the same prototype with different type name (note that the 2 types are the same at the end)

One of them is protected with #ifndef directive

I am considering adding a define to avoid the double declaration but have been told is not good practice to have the same name for a define definction and for a function name.

acg_header.h

```
    #ifndef ACos
    /* MATH::ACos/ */
    extern T_Float_user ACos(/* X/ */ T_Float_user X);
    #endif /* ACos */
```

manual_header.h

```
    #define ACos // suggested modification
    extern t_float ACos(const t_float X);
```

I would like to know if is is a correct solution regarding C implementation.

Comment: _"I have to deal with two header files declaring the same prototype with different type name (note that the 2 types are the same at the end)"_: this is pretty bad design in the first place.

Comment: `#ifndef` is a preprocessor *directive*, not a pragma.  A pragma is a different, specific kind of preprocessor directive.

Comment: @Jabberwocky agree...

Comment: What limitations do you have in how much you can do to fix this?  The proper fix is to reconcile the two header files so it's only declared in one, but I'm assuming you aren't able to do that for some reason like organizational structure, resource limitations, or time constraints.

Comment: acg_header is from automatic code genertion => can't touch this file and manual header is modifiable but I can't delete it

Comment: How can the two types be the same at the end if they are not the same at the declarations? In order for the compiler to process `extern T_Float_user ACos(T_Float_user X);`, `T_Float_user` must have been defined (with a `typedef`, which makes it an alias for some type). Similarly, in order for the compiler to process `extern t_float Acos(const t_float X);`, `t_float` must have been defined. If they are different names for the same type, there is no error; this should compile and run (in the absence of other issues). If they are different types, they are different and cannot be made the same.

Comment: A `typedef` does not create a new type. It only creates a synonym for a type. So if one header has `typedef struct foo T_Float_user` and another header has `typedef struct foo t_float`, then `T_Float_user` and `t_float` are the same type (provided `struct foo` is declared identically in both). Type names are not like structure names, where different structure tags create different types even if the structure contents are identical.

Comment: That said, there is probably no reason for manual_header.h to be redeclaring types or functions declared in acg_header.h. Likely it ought to simply include acg_header.h. Regarding “I have to deal with two header files declaring the same prototype with different type name”—Why? What is making you deal with that? Why do two headers have to declare the same prototype with different type names?

Answer (score 1):

You may have any number of *compatible* declarations of the same function or object.  It is not necessary or useful to play preprocessor games to avoid this situation.  This is why the standard approach is for each function or global variable to be declared in a (one) header file, and for each source that accesses or defines any function or object to include the appropriate header.  So, with respect to

> I have to deal with two header files declaring the same prototype with different type name

, no, you *shouldn't* have to deal with that.  There should be only one header declaring each function.  Nevertheless, if you do have two, and they declare the function compatibly, then you still have no problem, even if the declarations do not lexically match on account of the use of different -- but compatible -- type aliases.

If the declarations in your two header files are not compatible with each other, on the other hand, then you have a deeper problem.  At most one of them can be compatible with the function definition, and you must not use any other.

> I am considering adding a define to avoid the double declaration but have been told is not good practice to have the same name for a define definction and for a function name.

Again, your best bet is to skip this whole exercise, but if you choose to go ahead, then you need to understand that appearances in your code of an in-scope macro identifier will be replaced with the macro definition.  Thus, the result of preprocessing this:

> ```
> #define ACos // suggested modification
> extern t_float ACos(const t_float X);
> ```

would be

```
extern t_float (const t_float X);
```

, because you've defined `ACos` to expand to an empty sequence. The preprocessed result is invalid.  If you *must* follow this path, then define the macro to expand to its own name:

```
#define ACos ACos
```

You will then be able to test it via `#ifdef` directives, but you will avoid causing the preprocessor to mangle your program.  But again, really, don't do this at all.